# OLS model assumptions for ML

Tags: median, exploratory-data-analysis

hey i'm a beginner in data science,  started working on the familiar "Boston" dataset ,and i tried to fit a multiple linear regression model to predict the "median house price " , after preprocessing the data , i  was able to create , a model with an adjusted r squrared :75% , and  it performed well on test data ,the p value of shapiro test on residuals  is equal to 0.04 which i tried to maximize by reducing skewness and variability of data ,the durbin watson test is verified there is indebpendance of residuals , and also the mean is of residuals is centered around zero, there isn't that much variability in data .

my question is based on my situation , can i accept this model , if this violates normality  ,and do we only care about the performance of model on data test ? i tried to use transformers , and deleting some outliers in order to obtain   a model that fits the assumptions of "OLS" model , is it enough  ? do i need to verify all the assumptions ?,is my model poor ? thank's

Comment: If you want to predict medians, you should use quantile regression.

Comment: "deleting some outliers" is dangerous and bad practice.

Comment: I see five questions in the last paragraph, which is too many to answer. Choosing a question or two would help people who might answer. (Capitalizing the words and punctuating the sentences in a more standard way would also help.)